# Problem in uploading an image to my drupal site

Tags: media

My Drupal site contains images and videos of an event. I got a problem with image module. When I am uploading image an error `"The file could not be uploaded"` is displayed. I set the formats as jpg, jpeg, png.

I have a similar site in another server but it is free from this issue. It is uploading images smoothly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Check the permissions on the sites/default/files folder. Using linux you could do something like `sudo chmod -R 777 <foldername>`

Comment: Ya it worked Thanks for your valuable support @Krister Andersson

Comment: Glad you solved it. Although, I think the default permission for the `sites/default/files` folder should be 755.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check the permissions on the `sites/default/files` folder. Using linux you could execute `sudo chmod -R 755 <foldername>` from your terminal.

A good idea could also be to check your log files in order to track down the error. For example if you are running apache you could check the `/var/log/apache2/error_log` to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be in the size of image check the file upload limit and also the permission because image module works with proper permission.